# Any control like context menu in DevExpress?

Tags: vb.net, controls, devexpress, toolbox, contextmenu

I'm using controls from DevExpress to develop desktop application in VB.NET. Now, I want to add context menu also from DevExpress. But I cannot find such control in toolbox. Is it missing only in my version or DevExpress has not developed such context menu yet?

- Thank you in advance

Comment: yes, i mean windows forms..

Answer (score 2):

The XtraBars Suite allows you to create multi-purpose popup menus.
These menus can be used as dropdown lists for toolbar or ribbon buttons

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/context_menu.xml

also

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6587

Comment: how to create customized context menu for gridcontrol?

Comment: use GridView.PopupMenuShowing Event to show the popup menu.

this might help in designing the popup menu:
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument708

also:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A1386.aspx